# Converting C function code to C++ class method

Tags: c++, c

Hi I am trying to convert this function from C which prompts the user for a first name and last name and returns the first and last names in the ouput parametes

```
//the C codes is this:
void getPatronName(char *fn, char *ln) {
  printf("\n        Enter patron name ([first] [last]):  ");
  scanf("%s %s", fn, ln);
}

 //will it be equivalent to doing this in C++? :
 void MenUI::getPatronName(string *fn, string *ln) {
   cout<<endl<<"   Enter patron name ([first] [last]): ";
   cin>>*fn>>*ln;
 }
```

thanks,

Comment: Does the code work? What is the problem?

Comment: Why waste time translating unsafe C code to unsafe C++ code?  Get rid of the pointers.

Comment: Yes, it will work in a similar way. But what is your 'problem'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you convert from 'C' to C++, one of the things you should consider is to see if you can do things more safely than the `C` equivalent.

Take a look at the original `C` code:

```
void getPatronName(char *fn, char *ln) {
  printf("\n        Enter patron name ([first] [last]):  ");
  scanf("%s %s", fn, ln);
}
```

The issue here is that this function has no idea if `fn` or `ln` have allocated the proper space, or even if they are valid to write to (pointers are pointing to modifiable buffers).  So this function can easily crash.

A C++ translation that alleviates these issues would be this:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;
 //...
 void getPatronName(string& fn, string& ln) {
   cout << "\n   Enter patron name ([first] [last]: ";
   cin >> fn >> ln;
 }
```

Why is this safer?  First, you must pass a valid `std::string`'s to the function.  There is no chance (unless you do some sort of real hackery) of passing an invalid `std::string`.  The second thing is that fn and ln will allow input of string data of any size.  So the chance of a buffer overwrite is 0.

Answer (score 4):

use the >> operator and change the pointers to references

```
void MenUI::getPatronName(string& fn, string& ln) {
    cout<<endl<<"   Enter patron name ([first] [last]: ";
    cin>>fn>>ln;
}
```

Comment: +1, though two nit-picks with the question's coding - there's no reason to use `endl` rather than `\n` (the output will be flushed before `cin` is read from, as they're "tied" streams, so an extra `flush` just slows things down).  Separately, it would be much better to make the return type `bool` and `return cin >> fn >> ln;` so the caller can test whether the input was available....

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cin<<fn<<ln;
```

to

```
cin>>*fn>>*ln;
```

You need to dereference the pointers and change the direction of the operators.

Answer (score 0):

//the C codes is this:

```
void getPatronName(char *fn, char *ln) {
  printf("\n        Enter patron name ([first] [last]):  ");
  scanf("%s %s", fn, ln);
}

 //will it be equivalent to doing this in C++? :
 void MenUI::getPatronName(string* fn, string* ln) {
   cout<<endl<<"   Enter patron name ([first] [last]: ";
   cin>>*fn;
   cin>>*ln;
 }
```